# Third party plugin not override in joomla

Tags: plugins, joomla, overriding, joomla3.0

I have created a search plug-in in joomla that is "my-plug-in". When i tried to override this plug-in in joomla templates its not working.If i try to override any existing plug-in joomla its working. I have checked below link as well. This is working

[This link](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Plugin_Alternative_Layouts_.28Overriding_a_Plugin.29)

How i override my plug-in in joomla template.

I have added my plug-in below place.

```
plugins/search/my-plug-in

to 

templates/{TEMPLATENAME}/html/plg_search_my-plug-in
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have thoroughly checked the link that you have given you will find a line "**However you can only do it if the plugin is ready to allow overrides.** "

and

**Joomla provides a mechanism to override a plugin but this feature is not supported by all the plugins. Right now the only plugin in Joomla 3.x core that allow overrides is the Pagenavigation Content plugin that shows previous/next article links in article view of content component. There may be other plugins from third party developers allowing it and more core plugins will be overridable in the future.**

Do you have a tmpl folder inside your plugin as quoted here "**You will know when a plugin is overridable because has a /tmpl/ folder in it.** "

Also have you used `JPluginHelper::getLayoutPath()`. These are the requirements that need to be completed before you override layouts.
Check this code in pagenavigation plugin

```
// Output.
            if ($row->prev || $row->next)
            {
                // Get the path for the layout file
                $path = JPluginHelper::getLayoutPath('content', 'pagenavigation');
                // Render the pagenav
                ob_start();
                include $path;
                $row->pagination = ob_get_clean();
                $row->paginationposition = $this->params->get('position', 1);
                // This will default to the 1.5 and 1.6-1.7 behavior.
                $row->paginationrelative = $this->params->get('relative', 0);
            }
```

They have used JPluginHelper::getLayoutPath(); and you have to use

```
$path = JPluginHelper::getLayoutPath('search', 'my-plug-in');
```

You can check the pagenavigation plugin thoroughly to get a good idea.